# Replace backslash with inverted comma '\"' in Python while reading JSON

Tags: python, json, string

In a given string, I am trying to replace a backslash, followed by a double quote with nothing but nothing seems to be working. I have tried searching on SO as well but while there are plenty of solutions for replacing backslashes as well as for replacing quotes, I couldn't find one where both coming together could be replaced. Here I am giving a sample string.

```
sample_str = '{"source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "in_reply_to_status_id": null}'
```

I would like to modify it into a string like the following -

```
sample_str = '{"source": "<a href=http://twitter.com/download/iphone rel=nofollow>Twitter for iPhone</a>", "in_reply_to_status_id": null}'
```

So the only thing that I want to replace is where quotes are preceded by backslashes (and not ALL quotes, which is possible, if I remove backslashes and quotes separately).

I have tried the following but neither seems to be working (also tried it with regex but no luck!). I am sure I must have been missing something very obvious.

```
sample_str = sample_str.replace(r'\"', '')
sample_str = sample_str.replace('\\"', '')
```

I am reading these from a JSON dump of Tweets and trying to decode as JSON. But it turns out that because of this, the JSON library is not able to read it as a Python dictionary. I assumed this should have been taken care of by the library but it doesn't seem to work. So any solution that gets me the Python dictionary without this replacement will also be fine with me (and also preferable).

If I have missed some information, please let me know and I shall add that. Any help in this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of trying to work around it - what you have is perfectly valid JSON. Just make sure to escape it properly if you're entering it directly into a source file: `a = '{"source": "<a href=\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "in_reply_to_status_id": null}'` works fine with `json.loads(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to express it as a raw string by adding **r' '**. This is useful when dealing with backsplashes  '\' as raw strings leave backsplashes "as-is".

For example

```
import json 

sample_str = r'{"source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "in_reply_to_status_id": null}'

js = json.loads(sample_str)
print(js)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I guess I should have been more clear on this in my question - Here is how the JSON looks like in the original file that I have - `"{\"source\": \"<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for Android</a>\", \"in_reply_to_status_id\": null}"`. Now when I put this in a variable, it works fine. However, while reading from the file the exactly same line is not parsed as a Python dictionary (it is read as a string, instead and no error is generated by the JSON library). I was trying to figure out a way around this.

Comment: Victor, thanks for looking into this! The issue seems to be resolved for now but it was kind of a weird solution. While reading from file, I had to decode the JSON string twice in the sense that did a `loads` on the string that was returned by the first `loads` and that gave me the Dictionary that I was trying to get.